Can the existence of $e$ be proved in the real closed field theory?
Wikipedia says that the field of real algebraic numbers is a real closed field.
(1) So, the existence of the transcendental numbers such as $e$ cannot be proven in the real closed field theory.
(2) On the other hand, $e$ is the limit of the infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}$. The convergence of this series is a first-order proposition:  $\exists e\in\mathbb{R}, \forall \varepsilon >0, \exists N>0, \forall n>N, |e-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}|<\varepsilon$.  A real closed field is a field that has the same first-order properties as $\mathbb{R}$, so it is true in the field of real algebraic numbers.
(1) and (2) are contradictory.
Where am I wrong?

You cannot quantify over integers in this theory, only over reals.

Also you can not define the symbol $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$ in this theory.

(1) is sorta right, (2) is definitely wrong.
The field of real algebraic numbers constitutes a real-closed field, and this field contains no transcendental elements. This is an instance of a general model-theoretic phenomenon (omitting types). So (1) is kinda right.
Note, however, that one cannot even express the existence of a transcendental number as a first-order sentence in the language of ordered fields, let alone prove the existence of such a number in the first-order theory of real-closed fields! So your phrasing ("the existence of the transcendental numbers [..] cannot be proven in the real closed field theory") needs some adjustment.
Your argument for (2) is wrong. While it's true that any proposition $\varphi$ that you can state in the first-order language of ordered fields holds in a real-closed field precisely if it holds in $\mathbb{R}$, the convergence of this series cannot be stated in the first-order language of ordered fields.
Your quantifier $\exists N > 0$ is intended to range over the natural numbers. But as mentioned in the comments, the quantifiers in the first-order language of ordered fields are required to range over all elements of the field in question, and not the natural numbers. Moreover, your notation $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$ does not abbreviate any single formula of this language either: the formula that it abbreviates changes depending on the value of $n$.
